# Embedding a bash command inside the mv command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a directory that contains a list of files having the following format:

- 240-timestamp1.ts
- 240-timestamp2.ts
- ...
- 360-timestamp1.ts
- 360-timestamp2.ts

Now, I want to implement a bash command which matches the files that start with '240' and renames them so that instead of **'240-timestampX.ts'** the files look like **'240-human-readable-timestampX.ts'**.

I have tried the following:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin +5 -type f -name "240*"
    -exec mv $0 {$0/240-***and here I want to insert
    either stat -c %y filename or date -d @timestampX***} '{}' \;
```

I stuck here because I don't know if I can embed a bash command inside the mv command. I know the task may look a bit confusing and over-complicated, but I would like to know if it is possible to do so. Of course I can create a bash script that would go through all the files in the directory and while loop them with changing their respective names, but somehow I think that a single command would be more efficient (even if less readable).

- The OS is Linux Ubuntu 12.04.5
- The shell is bash

Thank you both [Kenavoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1344961/kenavoz) and [Kurt Stutsman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459615/kurt-stutsman) for the proposed solutions. Both your answers perform the task; however, I marked Kenavoz's answer as the accepted one because of the degree of similarity between my question and Kenavoz's answer. Even if it is indeed possible to do it in a cleaner way with omitting the find command, it is necessary in my case to use the respective command because I need to find files older than X units of time. So thank you both once again!

Comment: make a small script that "wraps" all the `mv` activity and uses `$1`, etc vars to receive variables. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to keep your `mmin` option, your can use `find` and process found files with a bash command using `xargs` :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin +5 -type f -name "240*.ts" | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'mv "${1}" "240-$(stat -c %y ${1}).ts"' \;
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash if all your files are in a single directory, you don't need to use `find` at all. You can do a for loop:

```
for file in 240-*; do
    hr_timestamp=$(date -d $(echo "$file" | sed 's/.*-\([0-9]*\)\.ts/\1/'))
    mv "$file" "240-$hr_timestamp.ts"
done
```

Comment: how can we run this? we need to create a separate `.sh` file and then run it like this:? `./script.sh` ?

Comment: You can type it directly into a shell. I usually do it as a single line with semicolons after each command inside the for loop. But you can do multiple lines as well.